# Django - Compress Audio File on Upload

Tags: django, html5-audio

I am using the HTML5 audio player in my Django project.

I tried uploading WAV and MP3 audio files, but only .mp3 with maximum of 2.5 MB work.

How can I compress the audio files on upload / what else can I do to increase the max file size?

Comment: where did you get 2.5 mb limit from?

Comment: doesnt upload any file bigger than 2.5 mb, maybe a limit from my server?